# Python Sqlite3- Python shell can create and edit databases but why can't a .py file create or access any database

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('new.db')
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE hello(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Message_type, time_sent, time_received, response)''')
```

The above program when executed from the python shell will execute and create a database by the said name but when i run the same program from a .py file,it won't create any table or database

Comment: How do you know that it didn't create the table? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: Because i manually check it by a database browser.-dbbrowser for sqlite

Comment: What happens if you add db.commit() and db.close() in the script?

Comment: Same results even if you add db.commit() & close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
from os.path import expanduser
db_dir = expanduser("~")
db=sqlite3.connect(db_dir+'/new.db')
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE hello(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Message_type, time_sent, time_received, response)''')
```

Now look in your home directory for `new.db`

Comment: The code that your provided me with created the database but its read only ,i cannot make any changes to it. Is there a way to make it read/write by any user?

Comment: That is probably because it is in your $HOME directory. Make `db_dir` equal to somewhere to which everyone else has access. `/home/public` or something.

Comment: I fixed it by some basic linux command that changes ownership of the created database.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the .py file did create the database file, but you aren't looking for the database file at the correct location. Add this to the end of your program:

```
print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new.db'))
```

Whatever it prints, look there for your database file.

Comment: Does the python shell and .py file save .db files in different directories?

Comment: That depends upon how they are each invoked. Since you don't specify how you invoke either, this seems like a possibility.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. However the data base is not in the location returned by the os.path command.